# Set WooCommerce user billing and shipping country programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, crud, usermetadata

I use WooCommerce and I build some custom functions.
The last thing what I want is set the country for billing and shipping programmatically.

I removed the input billing_country and shipping_country from the checkout page.

Is there a way to set the billing_country and shipping_country programmatically?

I tried `WC()->customer->set_shipping_country('US');` this set only the country for the cart and checkout page but does not send the country by submit.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the `WC_Customer` `save()` method…

You can use the following from a static or dynamic user ID *(the user Id is mandatory)*:

```
$country_code = 'US';

// Get the WC_Customer instance object from user ID
$customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );

$customer->set_billing_country( $country_code );
$customer->set_shipping_country( $country_code );
$customer->save();
```

Now it's saved as user meta data in the database.